# Does this above garage room need to support roof?

Tags: framing

I plan to extend my closet above the garage to make space for a washer and dryer. Do I need to build support beams for the roof? Or is it okay to build the knee wall anywhere? Any recommendations for a knee wall height? The ceiling is 8 ft and the pitch is 45 degrees. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to add additional supports for the roof? Probably not, unless you are removing existing structure. Do you need to make sure your garage roof can support your closet and washer and dryer? Absolutely.

Do not continue without engaging a structural engineer.

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking for one.